# To output the sbt compiler console log to txt at the build?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to use sbt console logs for CI/CD.

For example, I get logs when execute sbt console:

```
[info] compiling 6 Scala sources and 3 Java sources to D:\repos\app\template\target\scala-2.13\classes ...
...
[warn] 7 warnings found
[info] done compiling
```

I want to write the above output to the project's target/compiler_log.txt file.

I think I should write a configuration for log output in build.sbt, but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: A quick and dirty workaround is just doing `sbt compile >> log.txt`

Comment: Yes, I would also run the following as a work-around at this point.
`sbt compile 2>&1 > log.txt`
However I was wondering if there is an option to specify the output destination as a build tool to a file.